# How to access html information that is generated by javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, parsing

I am trying to get article headlines from [NY times](http://query.nytimes.com/search/advanced/#/%2a/since1851/allresults/1/allauthors/relevance/section_name%3A%22Business%22/) .

But I think the html is generated by javascript, as it is only visible when I use the 'inspect element' on firefox. 
How can I get to the articles? Probably, one of the ways is to emulate a browser but that seems like overkill.
I would prefer to do this in Java but Python is okay too. Your help is appreciated!

edit:
I tried using the api. But there are a lot of bad urls (page not found). Anyone has any more ideas on how to get the urls and headlines?

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) is probably what you're looking for; it's a browser automation framework.

You can use Python but Selenium actually uses Firefox to parse a site's content (last time I heard).

You can get the python version [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) but there are other [options](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a browser without GUI like [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). It has good JavaScript-support and you're able to read the contents of the page from your Java-program.

Answer (score 0):

As  an alternative solution to this particular problem, how about using the [New York Times API](http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/read/article_search_api_v2)? They provide JSONP for JavaScript support. Using the API is probably more future-proof if they ever change the site layout.